# Search from multiple databases in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I have two sites with different databases,which are on the same server.These sites are based on wordpress.One of them is forum and the other one is knowledgebase.I want to add a search box for these sites that searchs from two databases.Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sure is.

Step 1:
Learn MySQL query language

Step 2:
Make a stored procedure or view for the query

Step 3:
Attach it with a LIKE '%SEARCH_VALUE%' and return the result to your front-end.

Shouldn't be too hard. What are you searching for in Wordpress (it can be a pain because of the meta tables)